# Using vector analysis proof that a quadrilateral is in fact a paralelogram

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-analysis

[image: A paralelogram]

Let D be the midpoint of line segment AC.

Let E be simultaneously the midpoint of line segments CB and DF.

Please note that the rightmost point is labeled F.

Goal: Using vector analysis proof that quadrilateral [ABFD] is in fact a paralelogram.

any hints?

Comment: Which is the datum of the problem? Is the point F fixed or is it the outcome of your construction?

Answer (score 1):

Vectorially,$$\vec{BF}=\vec{BE}+\vec{EF}=\vec{EC}+\vec{DE}=\vec{DC}=\vec{AD}.$$